# PyCharm CE 2017.2.2: APPCRASH "Python has stopped working" randomly on Windows 7

Tags: python, c++, windows-7, pycharm, msvcr120.dll

I'm using Anaconda3 (Python 3.6) as my Python interpreter in PyCharm CE and as the IDE is loading in updates for the interpreter, Windows 7 throws an error. Here is the stack trace

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:   python.exe
>
> Application Version:    3.6.1150.1013
>
> Application Timestamp:  5914acba
>
> Fault Module Name:  MSVCR120.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:   12.0.40649.5
>
> Fault Module Timestamp: 56bc00d3
>
> Exception Code: 40000015
>
> Exception Offset:   0000000000074a46
>
> OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>
> Locale ID:  1033
>
> Additional Information 1:   b3bf
>
> Additional Information 2:   b3bffe3c48b4f560177850700e4a73f1
>
> Additional Information 3:   e02e
>
> Additional Information 4:   e02ea85e76f255c7787c2381f1154d1c

I've tried reinstalling Visual C++ but it's still happening. It seems to be happening when PyCharm is running this process here....

[PyCharm background tasks picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkB1G.png)

It just sticks there

Answer (score 2):

Deleting and re-creating virtual environment with base interpreter, re-installing required packages worked.